# send different types of post parameters in api in kotlin

Tags: android, post, kotlin

I try to send different types of post parameters in api but it did not work correctly. Any idea why?

Here is my code.

Firstly I wrap my parameters in a simple container and pass that as a parameter to AsyncTask, like this:

```
class MyParams {
    var paramName: String = ""
    var paramaddress: String = ""
    var paramlatitude: Float = 0.toFloat()
    var paramlongitude: Float = 0.toFloat()

    constructor(funName: String, funAddress: String, funLatitude: Float, funLongitude: Float) {
        this.paramName = funName
        this.paramaddress = funAddress
        this.paramlatitude = funLatitude
        this.paramlongitude = funLongitude
    }
}

class myClass : AsyncTask<MyParams, Void, String>() {

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg: String) {
        super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg)
        ...
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: MyParams): String {
        var name = params[0].paramName
        var address = params[0].paramaddress
        var latuitude = params[0].paramlatitude
        var longitude  = params[0].paramlongitude
        hashMap["name"] = name
        hashMap["address"] = address
        hashMap["latuitude"] = latuitude
        hashMap["longitude"] = longitude

        finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL)

        println("responseeeeeeeee-----="+finalResult)
        return finalResult
    }


}

val params = MyParams(funName,funAddress,funLatitude,funLongitude)
val myTask = myClass()
myTask.execute(params)
```

But in this line `hashMap["name"] = name` I got the following error:

> Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter V in inline
>       operator fun  MutableMap.set(key: K, value: V): Unit None
>       of the following substitutions receiver: MutableMap 
>       arguments: (String,Params) receiver: MutableMap 
>       arguments: (String,String) can be applied to receiver: HashMap  arguments: (String,String)

Comment: used retrofit 2.0 for ws calling it is easy.

Comment: how is your `hashMap` defined?

Comment: var hashMap = java.util.HashMap<String, MyParams>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you declared `hashMap` as a variable of type `HashMap<String, MyParams>`, while you're trying to `put` a `String`, and `String` "is not" `MyParams`.

To solve the issue, you should either change `MyParams` to `String` (i.e., `val hashMap = HashMap<String, String>()`, which I guess is what you really want), or insert the correct value inside the map (i.e., `hashMap["name"] = params[0]`).

By the way, `var paramlatitude: Float = 0.toFloat()` could be simplified to `var paramLatitude = 0F`

Comment: I did that but then it gives error in this line "hashMap["latuitude"] = latuitude" it says - Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter V in inline operator fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, V>.set(key: K, value: V): Unit
None of the following substitutions
receiver: MutableMap<String, String>  arguments: (String,String)
receiver: MutableMap<String, Float>  arguments: (String,Float)
can be applied to
receiver: HashMap<String, String>  arguments: (String,Float)

Comment: What is `httpParse`'s type? From which library is it from? I found another question using the same class (no link to the library, though), and there the `postRequest` method was accepting a `Map<String, String>` as a parameter, so it means that you need to convert your `latitude` and `longitude` to `String`, e.g., by calling `toString()` on them (but it depends on how the server expects input parameters to be formatted)

Comment: For latitude and longitude server expects input in Float.

Comment: ok, but I guess they should be passed as strings, since it's an HTTP request. Try to call `latitude.toString()` when adding it to your `Map<String, String>`, it should work

Answer (score 0):

`var name = params[0].paramName` is a String

`var address = params[0].paramaddress` is a String

So when you do :

```
hashMap["name"] = name
hashMap["address"] = address
```

using a Hashmap like this `var hashMap = java.util.HashMap<String, MyParams>()` it suppose you have to make an HashMap like HashMap and not HashMap.

Change the type of your Hashmap or send a type MyParams in the values of your Hashmap.